# How to check in ASP.NET if the user is online?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

what is the logic behind this on this website "last activity: 1 min ago from this ip address "
If you are obtaining the user's IP address in a hidden field , how can I do this in vb.net ?

And how can I check how many users are online using the application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET Membership service supports this feature. To get the particular user's last activity date, use [LastActivityDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastactivitydate.aspx) property and to indicate whether the user is online or not use [IsOnline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isonline.aspx) property. Also to get the number of online users, use [GetNumberOfOnlineUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline.aspx). Of course, the ASP.NET Membership service does not save the last IP address, and you have to override some behavior of `SqlMembershipProvider` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

for counting the online users see below links :

http://aspnetresources.com/blog/count_your_visitors.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Online-Active-Users.aspx

Answer (score -6):

Each ASP.net page has a Session with you can use to check if your useris online or not for example

```
   Session["IsOnline"] = "true";
```

then whenever user do not act with page (Asp.net engine) start to count +++++++

and when the count became more than what you specify in the Web.Config the session will Expire .
And When Session Expiered your user is offline.

Comment: @ whom -1 the answer. Do not forget type the reason

Comment: I am not your downvoter, but please read your own answer again and see if it makes any sense to you. I have *no* clue what you are suggesting :(